# How to keep camera always in horizontal position?

Tags: camera, bezier-curves, constraints, tracking, path

The camera is following the path from top to the bottom, orbiting around the wires. I would like it to be focused all the time on the wires in horizontal position. Is there a way to exclude Z axis from constraint tracking or any other method that would do the trick? Hope I make myself clear enough.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks like there's an empty, why don't you use it to keep your camera horizontal?

Comment: camera has no constant speed. I don't want to manually animate empty every time the camera speed change.

Comment: I think the solution would be to make empty's Z location always the same as Z location of the camera.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. All I needed to do is add constraint to empty - *copy location* and choose only Z location checkbox. Easy.

[image]